# jsPDF with colspan at the top of the table

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I'm trying to generate a PDF based on the image below

[image]

I can generate the pdf, but without the line with "Info" and "Contact". Is it possible to generate the pdf in the same way as in the image?

Below I have the code of the function I use to convert to pdf.

```
this.pdf = function(title, table, hideInfo) {
var doc = new jsPDF('l', 'pt', 'a4'), start = 65;

doc.setFont('helvetica');
doc.setFontSize(8);
doc.text(title, (doc.internal.pageSize.width - doc.getStringUnitWidth(title) * 8) / 2, 50);
doc.setFontSize(6);

doc.autoTable(table.columns, table.data, {
  startY: start,
  margin: { horizontal: 25 },
  styles: { overflow: 'linebreak', fontSize: 6, font: 'helvetica' },
  bodyStyles: { valign: 'top' },
  pageBreak: 'auto',
  theme: 'grid',
  columnWidth: 'wrap',
  headerStyles: { fillColor: [20, 167, 146] },
  drawCell: function(cell, data) {
    if (data.row.raw[0] && data.row.raw[0].toString().trim().toLowerCase() === 'total') {
      doc.setFillColor(233, 233, 233);
      doc.setFontType("bold");
    }
  }
});

doc.save(title.replace(/ /g,"_") + '.pdf');
};
```

Comment: Can you give us the code you have thus far?  It's hard to recommend anything without knowing what you have right now.

Comment: hi, I have just edited with the code.